# i want to get current day in Flask without date Ex: Monday

Tags: python, flask

I want to get the current day without date, month or year like.. Ex: Monday

```
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.now().day
```

I expect the output is Wednesday but the actual output is 28

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: Why do you expect that? https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.today().strftime('%A')
'Wednesday'
```